# Is there any way put python code on html?

Tags: python, html

umm.. I mean we can use javascript on html like this..

```
<body>
<script>
blah blah blah
</script>
</body>
```

Can we also python code using like above???
For example....

```
<body>
<python>
blah blah blah
</python>
</body>
```

Of course, It's not work.. So I want how can I use?

Answer (score 0):

No, Python cannot be used inside an HTML file. Most browsers only natively run HTML, CSS and JavaScript.